# Items count in OData v4 WebAPI response

Tags: count, odata, asp.net-web-api

How to return number of items in OData v4 HTTP response?

I need this number to pagination, so it should be number of items after filtering, but before 'skip' and 'top'.

I already tried passing '$inlinecount=allpages' and '$count=true' parameters in query options in url (https://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/06/13/web-api-and-odata-v4-queries-functions-and-attribute-routing-part-2/ - "Example of $count"), but my responses from WebAPI always have only query results (collection) - whole response looks like:

```
[
    {
        "Name":"name1", 
        "age":5
    }, 
    {
        "Name":"name2", 
        "age":15
    }
]
```

There is nothing like "odata.count" in the response.

I also tried returning PageResult instead of IQueryable in my WebAPI controller action (like described here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options#server-paging), but Request.GetInlineCount() is deprecated and its value is always null.

Any ideas?

[Update] I just found the same problem here: [WebApi with Odata NextPage and Count not appearing in the JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22854312/webapi-with-odata-nextpage-and-count-not-appearing-in-the-json-response) and I removed [EnableQuery] attribute and now my response looks like:

```
{
    "Items":
    [
        {
            "Name":"name1", 
            "age":5
        }, 
        {
            "Name":"name2", 
            "age":15
        }
    ],
    "NextPageLink":null,
    "Count":null
}
```

But still "Count" is always null. :(

---

Edit: After debugging and searching for count value in Request properties in my controller, I found out that correct Count value is in property named "System.Web.OData.TotalCount". So right now I exctract this value from that request property and my controller looks like that:

```
public PageResult<People> Get(ODataQueryOptions<People> queryOptions)
{
    var query = _context.People.OrderBy(x => x.SomeProperty);
    var queryResults = (IQueryable<People>)queryOptions.ApplyTo(query);
    long cnt = 0;
    if (queryOptions.Count != null)
        cnt = long.Parse(Request.Properties["System.Web.OData.TotalCount"].ToString());

    return new PageResult<People>(queryResults, null, cnt);
}
```

And it works fine, but I still don't know why I have to use workarounds like that.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could attach the controller method you wrote for getting the entity set.

Answer (score 12):

**For future reference (OData v4):**

First of all `$inlinecount` it's not supported in `OData v4` so you should use `$count=true` instead.

Second, if you have a normal `ApiController` and you return a type like `IQueryable<T>` this is the way you can attach a `count` property to the returned result:

```
using System.Web.OData;
using System.Web.OData.Query;
using System.Web.OData.Extensions;

//[EnableQuery] // -> If you enable globally queries does not require this decorator!
public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<People> queryOptions)
{
    var query = _peopleService.GetAllAsQueryable(); //Abstracted from the implementation of db access. Just returns IQueryable<People>
    var queryResults = (IQueryable<People>)queryOptions.ApplyTo(query);
    return Ok(new PageResult<People>(queryResults, Request.ODataProperties().NextLink, Request.ODataProperties().TotalCount));
}
```

> **Note:**
>   OData functionality does not supported by `ApiController`s so you
>   cannot have things like `count` or `$metadata`. If you choose to 
>   use simple `ApiController` the way above is the one you should use
>   to return a `count` property.

---

For a full support of OData functionality you should implement a `ODataController` the following way:

**PeopleController.cs**

```
using System.Web.OData;
using System.Web.OData.Query;

public class PeopleController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery(PageSize = 10, AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var res = _peopleService.GetAllAsQueryable();
        return Ok(res);
    }
}
```

**App_Start \ WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static void ConfigureOData(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    //OData Models
    config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "odata", routePrefix: null, model: GetEdmModel(), batchHandler: new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
    config.EnsureInitialized();
}

private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder
    {
        Namespace = "Api",
        ContainerName = "DefaultContainer"
    };
    builder.EntitySet<People>("People").EntityType.HasKey(item => item.Id); //I suppose the returning list have a primary key property(feel free to replace the Id key with your key like email or whatever)
    var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
    return edmModel;
}
```

Then you access your OData Api this way (example):

encoded uri:

```
http://localhost:<portnumber>/People/?%24count=true&%24skip=1&%24top=3
```

decoded:

```
http://localhost:<portnumber>/People/?$count=true&$skip=1&$top=3
```

References:

- [How to Use Web API OData to Build an OData V4 Service without Entity Framework](http://www.odata.org/blog/how-to-use-web-api-odata-to-build-an-odata-v4-service-without-entity-framework/)
- [Web API OData V4 Pitfalls](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidhardin/archive/2014/12/17/web-api-odata-v4-pitfalls-and-lessons-learned.aspx)
- [Create an OData v4 Endpoint Using ASP.NET Web API 2.2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint)

Comment: For further reference in ASP.NET Core the next link can be found at `Request.ODataFeature().NextLink`

Answer (score 4):

This can also be achieved by an action filter:

```
/// <summary>
/// Use this attribute whenever total number of records needs to be returned in the response in order to perform paging related operations at client side.
/// </summary>
public class PagedResultAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionExecutedContext"></param>
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
        if (actionExecutedContext.Response != null)
        {                
            dynamic responseContent=null;
            if (actionExecutedContext.Response.Content != null)
                responseContent = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>().Result;
            var count = actionExecutedContext.Response.RequestMessage.ODataProperties().TotalCount;
            var res = new PageResult<dynamic>() {TotalCount=count,Items= responseContent };

            HttpResponseMessage message = new HttpResponseMessage();
            message.StatusCode = actionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode;

            var strMessage = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            message.Content = strMessage;
            actionExecutedContext.Response = message;               
        }           
    }
}
```

And the custom PageResult class is:

```
public class PageResult<T>
{      
    public long? TotalCount { get; set; }
    public T Items { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
[PagedResult]
[EnableQuery()]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using OData conventional routing, $odata.count is not returned when your routes are not known to odata. Add 'app.UseODataRouteDebug();' to your ConfigureServices-method and then invoke 'https://localhost:5001/$odata'. If your route is not in the OData-route table, your route is not known to OData and you are not using correct naming conventions for your controller and EDM-type to be included in OData conventional routing.

Answer (score 1):

Will you please take a look at the sample service TripPin web api implementation at https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/blob/master/Scenarios/TripPin. You can follow the code in Airports controller and the service with the code http://services.odata.org/TripPinWebApiService/Airports?$count=true can return the count correctly.

Comment: It works at TripPin, but it still doesn't work in my application. :( After debugging and searching for count value in Request properties in my controller, I found out that correct Count value is in property named "System.Web.OData.TotalCount". So right now I exctract this value from that request property: `cnt = long.Parse(Request.Properties["System.Web.OData.TotalCount"].ToString())`
(More about this workaround is in my edited post above)

Comment: is it possible to set the default $count=true in server level?

Answer (score 1):

That's what I am using with oData v4:

```
Request.ODataProperties().NextLink, 

Request.ODataProperties().TotalCount
```

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example, please?